# Stopping and starting a server in a python script using subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

From my python script i need to stop and start Weblogic server multiple number of times.

If we need to do that manually (stopping or starting the server ) in linux

I go to 
    mwhome+"/user_projects/domains/bifoundation_domain/bin
and execute the command

```
./stopWeblogic.sh
```

ANd to start the server in a terminal i execute the command

```
./startWeblogic.sh
```

And i need to replicate this in my python code.

```
wlserverstop=mwhome+"/user_projects/domains/bifoundation_domain/bin/stopWebLogic.sh"
output3 = subprocess.call([ wlserverstop ])

#starting weblogic server
wlserver=mwhome+"/user_projects/domains/bifoundation_domain/bin/startWebLogic.sh"
output4 = subprocess.Popen([ wlserver],stderr=STDOUT, stdout=PIPE)
time.sleep(200)
```

1) As the stopWeblogic server will terminate and return i used subprocess.call()
2) As the startWeblogic server will not terminate and a process needs to be running in the background i used subprocess.Popen()

But the problem is the stopping and starting of servers is not happening properly.
Some times it doesnot start and sometimes even if the server starts when i put a stopserver command immeadiately it runs forever.

Any better way to do this ? Thanks

Comment: You probably need to take a look at the `.communicate()` method on a `Popen` object.  Data may be getting emitted to stdout and/or stderr and may be blocking the process because the pipe is full.  The `communicate()` method will help with that problem.

Comment: Can you use Weblogic Scripting Language (WLST) instead? It's jython and should work well with any existing python you have. It is more suited for the job of starting machines. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/config_scripting/manage_servers.html#start_admin_server

Comment: @jszakmeister thanks! solved the problem :)